Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of an equation $x^2-4x+1=0.$ Find the value of $\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}$
Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be the roots of an equation $x^2-4x+1=0.$ Find the value of $\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}$
This is what I have tried: So I know that $\alpha\beta=1\Rightarrow \alpha=\frac{1}{\beta}$, from here we  have $$\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}=(\frac{1}{\beta})^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}=\beta^{\alpha-\beta}$$ and $$|\alpha-\beta|=\sqrt{12} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \alpha , \beta = 2\pm \sqrt{3}. $$
Assume $\alpha\geq \beta$, Then the $\alpha^{\beta}\beta^{\alpha}$ is
$$(2-\sqrt{3})^{\sqrt{12}}=(7-2\sqrt{3})^{\sqrt{3}}$$
Any other solutions are appreciated

Why not start by solving the quadratic?

$\alpha > \beta \implies \alpha^\beta \times \beta^\alpha = [ ~\alpha \times \beta ~]^\beta \times \beta^{\alpha - \beta}.~$  As suggested, calculate explicit values for $~\alpha, \beta ~: ~\alpha > \beta,~$ and calculate $~\alpha \times \beta.$

geetha290krm, I think this method would be simpler

I disagree.  Just try geetha290krm's method, coupled with my comment.

The equation $x^2-4x+1=0$ has two real solutions:
$$\alpha,\beta=\frac{4\pm \sqrt{16-4}}{2}=\frac{4\pm 2\sqrt{3}}{2}=2\pm \sqrt{3}$$
Then, you have that:
$$\alpha\cdot \beta=(2+\sqrt{3})(2-\sqrt{3})=4-3=1\Longrightarrow \alpha=\frac{1}{\beta}$$
Therefore, $$\alpha^\beta \beta^\alpha=\left(\frac{1}{\beta}\right)^\beta\beta^{\frac{1}{\beta}}=\beta^{-\beta}\beta^{\frac{1}{\beta}}=\beta^{\frac{1-\beta^2}{\beta}}=(2-\sqrt{3})^{\frac{1-(2-\sqrt{3})^2}{2-\sqrt{3}}}$$
Computing the exponent:
$$\frac{1-(2-\sqrt{3})^2}{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{1-(4+3-4\sqrt{3})}{2-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{-6+4\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}\cdot \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2+\sqrt{3}}=2\sqrt{3}$$
So, you conclude that $$\alpha^\beta \beta^\alpha=(2-\sqrt{3})^{2\sqrt{3}}$$
Note. You could have choosen $\beta=\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and it would have been the same.

Alternatively, with $~\alpha > \beta,~$ you have that $~\alpha ~\beta = 1,~$ so $$\alpha^\beta ~\beta^\alpha = [\alpha ~\beta]^\beta \times \beta^{\alpha - \beta} = 1 \times \beta^{2\sqrt{3}}.$$

Let $a$ and $b$ be the roots of $x^2-4x+1=0$. Then $a+b=4$ and $ab=1$ and so
$$a^bb^a=a^{4-a}(1/a)^a=a^{4-a}a^{-a}=a^{4-2a}=(a^2)^{2-a}.$$
Of course $a^2=4a-1$ and $(2-a)^2=a^2-4a+4=3$ and so $2-a=\pm\sqrt{3}$, so
$$(a^2)^{2-a}=(4a-1)^{\pm\sqrt{3}}=(7\mp4\sqrt{3})^{\pm\sqrt{3}}.$$
The argument also shows that either choice of sign yields the same result.

You need to be careful when using exponent laws. $x^{2y} = (x^2)^y$ is not always true. How do you know you can use it here?

@jjagmath Within real analysis, your comment is very interesting to me.  Could you please expand on what you are thinking?

@user2661923 Consider the following example: for a positive number, the usual interpretation of $x^{1/2}$ is the positive square root of $x$. But then notice that $((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$ while $(-1)^{2\times 1/2}=(-1)^1=-1$. The exponent rule $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ can be safely used when $x>0$. Otherwise some complications may occur.

@jjagmath This is what I thought that you were thinking, but I did not want to presume.  Since $~a \geq 2 - \sqrt{3}, ~a > 0.~$  Further, since $~7^2 > 4^2 \times 3,~$ you have that $~7 - 4\sqrt{3} > 0,~$ so Servaes' use of the exponent law is valid.  I am guessing that this was the intent of your initial comment.

@user2661923 My point is that there is no mention in the answer about the fact that $a$ is positive. Without that remark there is no way to know if Servaes is aware of the necessity of the condition and consider it too obvious to mention, or if Servaes is unaware of it and using the exponent law without knowing that is not always valid.
